# Loading Huge resolution images causing Heap error in j2me

Tags: heap-memory, java-me

I am trying to load a 3776 * 2816 PNG, 24 bit image - 804KB onto my phone , the MOTO ROKR e6.It gives up with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError,Is their a general way to handle loading such high resolution images.The phone's internal memory is only 8MB, I think this has something to do with the error.

I have also, tried to split the image to 16 parts and load them, still there seems to be some limit on what it can handle.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just some quick calculations:

```
24 bits = 3 bytes
space required (in bytes) = 3776 * 2816 * 3 
                          = 31,899,648 bytes
                          = 31.9MB
```

That means once you've loaded the image (using ImageIO or JAI or whatever) you need 31.9MB to store the raw image data.  As a result you can't load it on a device with only 8MB of memory (and I'm assuming no other kind of swap space).

You could load the raw file as bytes of data rather than an image -- the data is heavily compressed -- but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: So,it looks like there is no way to load the image :( .Guess my phone's old. I was trying to write an application similar to google maps for displaying this high resolution static image that I could zoom out/in.

Comment: You could try tiling the image into smaller segments, and then load relevant segments.  If you're building a zoom application you could consider building multiple images at varying resolution (by downsampling) before loading them onto your phone.